# lookup jndi resource without resource-ref definition

Tags: java, jndi

I would like to lookup a datasource defined on application server but without define a resource-ref on web.xml. The name of jndi resource is defined on an external file in my web application. I did a lot experiment on Tomcat but it seems not possible. It's possible to define at runtime a resource "resource-ref"? Do you have some suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question. And here is what I found: instead add in web.xml you can modify the 'context.xml' either in Tomcat or in /META-INF/condext.xml in your application and add a resource there:

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/EmployeeDB" auth="Container"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         description="Employees Database for HR Applications"/>
</Context>
```

But I didn't find if it's possible to do this programmatically.

[link to tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions)